# Problem reading a file with Scanner and a cycle

Tags: java, file

I have two different kinds of input in a file. 
First line has the number of Tasks that must be created, then the next following lines have the data each task must have, for example, lets say the file has

```
4
Task1 4, 5
Task2 2, 7
Task3 8, 9
Task4 7, 2
//followed by other data
```

I want to create an array for the tasks, and then read the info each task must contain.
So I tried:

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("Readthis.txt"));
int numberOfTasks =inFile.nextInt();

Tasks myTasks = Tasks[numberOfTasks];

for (int i=0;i<numberOfTasks;i++)
{
  String line = inFile.nextLine();
  String[] temp = line.split(" ");
  String TaskName = temp[0];
  int TaskDuration = Integer.valueof(temp[1]);
  //and the other process for the third number 
}
```

My problem is, it sets the number of tasks as 4, no problem, but, when starting the "for" cycle it reads line as "" and doesn't read "Task1 4 5" and so on,

so right now it throws and exception because temp[0] is empty, but it should be the task's name.

Shouldn't Scanner keep reading where it left off? after it read the first "4"? I'm confused.

How do I get it to work as I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use nextInt() but nextLine() to read a file line by line.

Try to replace the nextInt() line with the following:

```
int numberOfTasks =Integer.parseInt(inFile.nextLine());
```

The code will read the whole line (containing the 4 number in your example), and will try to parse it into an Integer.

The nextInt() will read the next token, and not the whole line, so after nextInt() read the 4 number, the new line bytes (\n) is left for the nextLine() to read.

Check [Java 8 Scanner API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()).

> public int nextInt()
>
> Scans the next token of the input as an int.
>
> ...

Comment: Thank you very much! That is very useful